# Python Tkinter - Insert() missing 1 required positional argument:

Tags: python, tkinter

I get the error, how can I fix it. I've been dealing for hours

**Error:**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\imonu\Desktop\patient-information-system\stok.py", line 129, in Insert
    self.database.Insert(self.idEntry.get(), self.s_adEntry.get(), self.s_grupEntry.get(), self.s_birimEntry.get(), self.a_tarihEntry.get(), self.a_fiyatEntry.get(), self.s_fiyatEntry.get(), self.sg_miktarEntry.get(), self.m_miktarEntry.get(), self.t_iletisimEntry.get(), self.s_aciklamaEntry.get())
TypeError: Insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 's_aciklama'
```

> Project File
>   https://pastebin.pl/view/8558b2c5

Comment: Please try to cut your code down to the smallest portion needed to demonstrate the problem, and include it directly in the question (not with a pastebin link).

Comment: looks bad . ...

Comment: Anyway, you have a simple typo: you are missing the value for the `t_ad` parameter. To avoid this sort of problem, you may find it easier to use tools such as `collections.namedtuple` to gather up your parameters and avoid typing out long lists of names.

Comment: I rewrite it over and over again but it keeps giving the error

Comment: You need to pay more attention to detail. I cannot help you with that.

Comment: thnax u ........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending 1 parameter `t_ad`. you have to pass this `self.t_adEntry.get()` to
solve the error.

```
def Insert(self):
    self.values = Values()
    self.database = Database()
    self.test = self.values.Validate(self.idEntry.get(), self.s_adEntry.get())
    if (self.test == "SUCCESS"):
        self.database.Insert(self.idEntry.get(), self.s_adEntry.get(), self.s_grupEntry.get(), self.s_birimEntry.get(), self.a_tarihEntry.get(), self.a_fiyatEntry.get(), self.s_fiyatEntry.get(), self.sg_miktarEntry.get(), self.m_miktarEntry.get(), self.t_adEntry.get(), self.t_iletisimEntry.get(), self.s_aciklamaEntry.get())
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Veriler Başarıyla Eklendi")
    else:
        self.valueErrorMessage = "Invalid input in field " + self.test
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Value Error", self.valueErrorMessage)
```